# Reliably targeting correct Azure Managed Disk on a Linux VM using an Ansible playbook

Tags: linux, azure, ansible, azure-managed-disk

How do I reliably partition and mount the file system of an Azure Managed Disk on a Linux VM using Ansible playbooks?

I can create an Azure Managed Disk with `azure_rm_manageddisk` and assign it to a VM instance. My issue starts when I'm trying to take the disk into use. I just don't know how to reliably target the correct managed disk anymore for partitioning and file system mounting.

Neither `azure_rm_manageddisk` nor `azure_rm_manageddisk_info` seems to return a reliable, unambigious id for the disk that could be referred from the OS side.

I don't think the disk even shows up on `blkid` before it has been partitioned.

Microsoft has documented that

> By default when you create a VM, Azure provides you with an OS disk (/dev/sda) and a temporary disk (/dev/sdb). All additional disks you add show up as /dev/sdc, /dev/sdd, /dev/sde and so on.

(source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/optimization)

but this doesn't seem reliable. I think I saw my VM have a setup different from this right after creation and this is definitely going to change after reboot. So no trusting `/dev/sdc` in my opinion. A rerun of a playbook could cause all kinds of havoc, if the block device files aren't stable. I actually managed already to make my root partition visible at `/media/my_data_disk_mount`.

Is this just something I will have to handle manually? Seems odd. It's such a common thing to do.

There's also `/dev/disk/azure/resource` for example, but that seemed to lead to messy results also.

(source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-device-names-problems)

Maybe something with the LUN numbers?

Comment: Did you try to gather facts on the vm and look at `ansible_devices`? Quick oneliner example to have a look at the var structure on your localhost: `ansible localhost -m setup -a filter=ansible_devices`. You should have what you're looking for in there on your remote target.

Comment: If you do not trust the things such as `/dev/sdc`, you can use the UUID as the advice the troubleshooting provide. And what else do you expect?

Comment: As I see it, both of these suggestions are valid, but there's a missing link somewhere. How am I supposed to know which disk is the one that I want?  I've already sort of lost the handle. Basically I could try to infer which disk to target based on disk size, but that smells bad. There are three or more disks to choose from. I have to pick one before I can get get the correct UUID, for example. How do I go about that step in a reliable manner? I don't know the UUID at this stage and must find out which disk to read the UUID from. There's probably something really simple I'm missing...

Comment: Any more updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the messages, you want to find the correct disk and get the UUID to mount. What you think is right. You can use the LUN of the disk to judge which one is you want. You can use the command `tree /dev/disk/azure` and it shows as below:

[image]

You can see the disk `/dev/sdc` use the lun1. And you can also find which disk is using the lun1in the Azure portal. And then you can use the command `sudo blkid` to get the UUID after you init the disk:

[image]